# mobile screen keep rotation when button pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, mobile-browser

see http://liveweave.com/0POip0

i want when user keeps "rotate" text pressed the group object keeps on rotation ?
 as soon as user removes touch press stop rotationg

```
$('#rotate').on({
    'mousedown touchstart click': function () {
         var x=setInterval(function () {group.setAngle(group.getAngle()+30);canvas.renderAll();}, 3000);
        return false;
    },
    'mouseup touchend': function () {
      clearInterval(x);
    }
});
```

getting error **Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#rotate').on({
    'mousedown touchstart click': function () {
        var x=setInterval(function () {group.setAngle(group.getAngle()+30);canvas.renderAll();}, 3000);
        return false;
    },
    'mouseup touchend': function () {
        clearInterval(x);``
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello, and Welcome to StackOverflow. When you answer a question, please tell us about your solution rather than just posting a code snippet :)

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined

Answer (score 0):

solve need to initialize value of var x

```
var x=null;
$('#rotate').on({
    'mousedown touchstart click': function () {
         var x=setInterval(function () {group.setAngle(group.getAngle()+30);canvas.renderAll();}, 3000);
        return false;
    },
    'mouseup touchend': function () {
      clearInterval(x);
    }
});
```